# System.Net.WebClient() DownloadUsingWebClientAsync working in .netcore 3.1 but not with .netcore 2.2 (behind proxy)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, webclient

I did POC on my office machine to download a zip file, extract and do some process. I showcased this using a console app however, this needs to go to azure functions app. So I made sure I am using the matching framework (.netcore 2.2) which is running in production. This is working perfectly as intended.

Below is the code snippet to download the file:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DownloadFile
{
    class Program
    {

        private static string url = @"http://somesite.com/somefile.dat";

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading...");

                await DownloadUsingWebClientAsync(url, Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "avvdat.ini"));

                Console.WriteLine("Download complete");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message.ToString());
            }
            Console.Write("Press ENTER key to end");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static async Task DownloadUsingWebClientAsync(string url, string filePath)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, Path.Combine(filePath));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I ran the same code (console app) in my client's vm this is failing with below error (SS of error log)

[image]

Soon I realized our client's VMs are behind a proxy and uses .pac (proxy script file in IE) to auto-detect settings.

[image]

I made slight changes to code to use proxy settings

```
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxy.clientsite.com/internet_proxy.pac");
await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, Path.Combine(filePath));
```

This is now giving me error

[image]

I am sure 404 is not related the download url because its unchanged/correct.

Now, when I changed the framework to .netcore 3.1, the code without proxy setting is working.

I am not sure why is this but it must be 3.0 is taking care of proxy settings internally. Is there a way I can do it using 2.2? because I am not yet authorized to upgrade to 3.1

Comment: Ask the client to remove the proxy from VMs ?

Comment: that's impossible

Comment: Nothing is impossible.  If the only 2 options are upgrade to 3.1 (3.0 is now unsupported remember), or remove the proxy, then maybe ask the client to decide.

Comment: I have changed 3.0 to 3.1. So you are saying its not possible to use 2.2 with proxy behind?

Comment: WebClient is obsolete, fully replaced by HttpClient *especially* in .NET Core. All new development, all performance features are build for HttpClient, for quite some time now. Unlike WebClient, HttpClient is thread-safe and *meant* to be reused.

Comment: @SolowDeveloper `I am not yet authorized to upgrade to 3.0 or 3.1` What 3.0? That's already out of support. Did someone give authorization to use an unsupported runtime? Seriously -  The Long-Term-Support version is 3.1, that's common knowledge ever since the 3.0 roadmap was announced. The .NET team stressed that at every point, every blog, every speech. You should probably ask for written permission to use the decommisioneed 3.0 version (that's a joke)

Comment: For the official blogs and news - [.NET Core 3.0 will reach End of Life on March 3, 2020](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-0-end-of-life/) and [.NET Core Supported OS Lifecycle Policy](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/os-lifecycle-policy.md)

Comment: `"http://proxy.clientsite.com/internet_proxy.pac"` is the URL to the configuration file, not the proxy URL. Download that file and check the actual URL address.